# How to override the get method of a python dictionary using UserDict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, inheritance

I'm currently using UserDict to override some dictionary methods. What I'm trying to do is to rewrite the default "get" method of a dictionary to be able to pass it a path and avoid calling the get method over and over again.

Here is my code :

```
class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, path):
        keys = path.split("/")
        value = self.data

        for key in keys:
            if isinstance(value, list):
                value = [ v.get(key) if v else None for v in value]
            else:
                value = value.get(key)

            if not value:
                break

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return MyDict(value)


        return value
```

Everything works fine however, I would like to be able to access to a default value. I would like to be able to do something like this :

```
my_json = {
    "name": "John"
}
dict = MyDict(my_json)
children = dict.get("children", [])
```

Here I would like children to be an empty array but I cannot access the default value (the empty array) in the **get_item** method so children is equal to None...

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed how `[` ... `]` works.

To override `.get( ... )`, simply `def get`.

nit: Prolly best to avoid assigning to identifiers like `dict`, `dir`, `list`, or `map`,
since then you'll have trouble accessing certain builtins.